# Material Tabs animation pauses with CanDeactivate gaurd, but never continues

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using Material Tabs for my subnav. Navigating between tabs will change the route and display a new component. I have one tab with a form that will stop the user from navigating away with a CanDeactivate guard if there are unsaved changes. When this happens, a dialog opens asking the user if it is okay to discard changes. If they click the button to discard, it will continue navigating to the new tab.

This all works great, except for the animation. The guard stops the animation and prevents the new tab from being underlined, as you would expect since the routing was stopped, but once the navigation continues, the newly active tab is not underlined. Instead, the previous tab is underlined, despite the new route and new content being displayed. How can I get the animation to continue when it continues routing to the new tab so the correct tab is active/underlined?

Comment: would it be possible for you to create an stackblitz example for this?